# Primefaces Command button causes page reloading

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working an primefaces application, I am using 
Primefaces 5.x version, Jsf 2.x

which has tabview
in one of the tabs I have command button, by clicking on it pdf export should happen.

For the first time click on button page is getting reloaded, from the second time on words request is going to bean page and downloading is working correctly.

this is my code snippet for command button :

`<h:form id="mainForm">`

```
<p:tabView id="myId" activeIndex="#{bean.currentTabIndex}" dynamic="true" cache="false">

<p:tab title="vehicle" id="vehId" styleClass="panelBack">
    <h:form id="exportForm">
       // some code


<p:commandButton value="export"  process="@this"  actionListener="# {bean.export()}" ajax="false" id="exportButton" />
        </h:form>

    </h:form>
```

If I make dynamic = false, it's working. I mean after clicking export button request is going to bean class, export is working.

What would be the problem? Can somebody help me?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Comment: Nmber 2 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Answer (score 0):

Yes your problem is most likely nested  that is not allowed in JSF.

Comment: Then please vote to close as a duplicate, No need to answer then. And nested forms is not allowed in html, not only jsf

Comment: Sorry i have never voted to close as a duplicate.  Can you instruct on how?  According to this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions I need 3000 reputation?

Comment: Sorry You are right I did not think about the reputation Points You Need For This

Comment: But Maybe you can Flag it for moderation and in the command State that it can be closed end Sorry For All The Wrong capitalization Google Voice Recognition is not doing A Very Good Job Here